# Using /dev/shm folder for pid files on RHEL6/CentOS6?

Tags: centos6, rhel6, pid, tmpfs

RHEL7/CentOS7 has a dedicated folder: $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (e.g. /run/user/1000) for pid files, that folder is a tmpfs. However RHEL6/CentOS6 does not have $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR.

RHEL6(also RHEL7) has a folder using similar type: /dev/shm. After some testing and searching on Internet, I realize it's convenient place for IPC purpose, and also seems OK to put small pid files in it.

So the question is: Are there any *drawbacks* of using this folder for the pid files.

(Example of not using other folder like /tmp: there is a crontab job removes pid files every certain days causing service unstable)

> Reference:
>
> https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmpfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On RHEL 6, PID files are almost always in `/var/run` or a subdirectory thereof. This directory is only cleared at boot time. On RHEL 7, this directory is now `/run` and `/var/run` is symlinked to it for backward compatibility.

The directory you mention, [$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), is used by *user* processes, not *system* services.

You aren't really meant to abuse `/dev/shm` for this though. This directory exists for processes which [communicate via shared memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand015.html) to provide a backing store.

Comment: Thanks for the explain. The services are run as non-root user and the home dir is NFS, so I'm looking for a reliable place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this area to place pid files, no drawbacks.
Actually you can place pid files anywhere your app have write access to. It is a convention to place pid files in certain places, to easily locate them and to not pollute everything around.
Additionally, placing files in tmpfs you could be sure there will be no old pid-files after system reboot.